# rails application on nginx http and https access denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

I'm deploying a Rails application on personal server using Nginx, phusion_passenger. I've site configuration file with following server blocks. With this configuration my `http://192.168.1.121` service doesn't work while `https://192.168.1.121` fails with forbidden (access denied) error.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

        # Make site accessible from http://192.168.1.121/
        server_name 192.168.1.121;

        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
        root /home/deploy/www/myrailsapp/current/public;
        index index.html index.htm;

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
                root html;
        }
} 

server {
       listen 443;
       server_name 192.168.1.121;

       passenger_enabled on;
       rails_env production;
       root /home/deploy/www/myrailsapp/current/public;
       index index.html index.htm;

       ssl on;
       ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
       ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

       ssl_session_timeout 5m;

       ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
       ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
       ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

       error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
       location / {
               try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
       }
}
```

production.rb has force_ssl: true
  Also, If I remove server {} block with https entry, application works on http just fine (of course I've to comment out force_ssl: true from production.rb). I'm very puzzled by the access denied error if the same directory is accessed from https.
- nginx version: nginx/1.6.2
- Rails 4.0
- Ruby 2.1.3
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try configuring the SSL on the same `server` block as your `port 80` configuration.

Also, it's [recommended to use the `ssl` parameter of the `listen` directive](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html#ssl)  for `port 443`, instead of the `ssl on` directive.

So something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    # Use ssl parameter on the listening socket instead of the 'ssl on' directive
    listen 443 ssl; 

    server_name 192.168.1.121;

    # Rest of your ssl configuration here
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;
    ssl_session_timeout 5m;

    ssl_protocols SSLv3 TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers "HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5 or HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5:!3DES";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    passenger_enabled on;
    rails_env production;
    root /home/deploy/www/myrailsapp/current/public;
    index index.html index.htm;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root html;
    }
}
```

Sources and Recommended Reading:

- [Official nginx docs - A single HTTP/HTTPS server](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server)
- [Digital Ocean tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-14-04) (may or may not be helpful for your case)